# Port-foward command to access postgres from outside AKS not working in kubectl due to ampersand

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubectl, bitnami, azure-aks

I am trying do deploy PostgreSQL on AKS from the following Bitnami chart: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/upstreamed/postgresql/#installing-the-chart

During deployment, I have been invited to use the following command (once installed) to make sure I will be able to access postgres outside the cluster (e.g. some local DBMS)

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/dozing-coral-postgresql 5432:5432 & PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
```

This results with a syntax error:

```
At line:1 char:80
+ ... d --namespace default svc/dozing-coral-postgresql 5432:5432 & PGPASSW 
...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for 
future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as 
part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

What would be the correct command to unclock the ports?

Comment: `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: not sure how that might work even in theory, as port-forward is a blocking command, next command will never execute. also, you are using powershell, this is targeted at bash since powershell doesnt have a `&&` operator

Comment: Actually the notice that this is bash command was very helpful. I am using PowerShell with Azure CLI on Windows 10. I have entered bash mode using `sh` and now I have new error, but problem with ampersand is solved

Answer (score 3):

The output you should see is something like

```sh
To connect to your database from outside the cluster execute the following commands:

    kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/jolly-raccoon-postgresql 5432:5432 &
    PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
```

There are two different commands. The first one is to forward the ports, and the final `&` is to send this command to the background so you are able to continue using the shell

```sh
$ kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/jolly-raccoon-postgresql 5432:5432 &
[1] 62447
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 5432
```

The second command allows you to connect to the database using the forwarded port from another host where you have installed the `psql` client

```
$ PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
psql (11.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: So the first one is for PowerShell I use to communicate with Azure (using Azure CLI) and the second for bash on host with postgres?

Comment: Yes, `kubectl port-forward` should be executed in the same host were you executed `helm install`. The one about `psql` (with the password as environment variable) can be executed in the same host if you run it using 127.0.0.1 or localhost in the `--host` flag or you can execute from another host using the proper IP